# grammatical tense in a clause attached to the present-perfect-tense sentence

Tags: grammar

What grammatical tense should I use in a clause attached to the present-perfect-tense sentence?

> Her chance to perform has often been stolen by other more active
>   students, which she herself never **minded**.

or

> Her chance has often been stolen by other more active students, which
>   she herself never **minds**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either might be valid, depending on the sense of what you are trying to convey. There is no rule that a verb in a prepositional phrase must agree with the main verb of the sentence. It is just necessary that it make sense - it is the **semantics** that matter, the meaning.

In this case, it is much more likely, to my mind, that you mean the sense of your second example, using the simple present. It is making a general statement - she never minds that. Using the simple past, it is saying that she never minded it when it happened.

You could also say *has never minded*, which would fit sometimes, or *will never mind*, which would be an odd thing to say but not semantically invalid. Using any form of the progressive would be non-idiomatic at least, and arguably incorrect at worst.

Comment: To me the first sentence seems more likely, although I agree that, without more context, either is possible.